# Is it possible to disable jQuery's mobile responsive design?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

It's pretty straightforward. I've built a layout using jQuery Mobile UI, but i don't want the responsive layout functionality. Is it possible to remove it?

Comment: What part of responsiveness do you want to remove? You need to be more specific.

Comment: All of it. I want the same layout for every device, regardless of the screen size.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to do this. Even if you use only UI elements they are all made to be responsive so you are out of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this?... wrap a wrapper div to all of your contents in the `data-role="content"` section.

Then give the fixed width to this wrapper.

Like that,

## HTML

```
<div data-role="content">
    <div class="resize_box">
        <!-- your content here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.resize_box{
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```