# How to make a panel unresponsive in Primefaces?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I want to make all components in a panel unresponsive in Primefaces. In mobile phone size their positions change. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Please add your code and show what you ve done so far.

Comment: I just tried to give a min-width size to panel but it did not worked. Components inside of panel flows when I make screen size small than min-width size of panel.

Comment: 1) "I" is always capital case on English. 2) Your sentence *"In mobile phone size their positions change."* is incomprehensible, extend and explain it.

Comment: PrimeFaces uses jQuery UI so I've linked this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16924081/is-it-possible-to-disable-jquerys-mobile-responsive-design  - You could also disable all themeing and theme it yourself. This is a CSS/Layout issue not a direct primefaces requirement.

Comment: Thank you @VeenarM

Comment: @peterh leave coding and go to a preparatory school. Maybe, you can have a better career there.

Comment: I am so sorry that I am trying to [advice](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370) a [functional illiterate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_illiteracy), instead of silently voting down them and step away, as others do. I think your writing "quality" suggest you the re-visit of the elementary, and not to me.

Comment: @peterh Why should I re-visit elementary? Because of lowercase i? Don't be foolish man. Here is programing area, it seems that here is not for you, go prep school and try to teach language to little children. Maybe you can be helpful in this manner.

Comment: I never heard in my life that writing over the quality of a 8 year old child would be forbidden for programmers. On my opinion, it is false information you got somewhere. Actually, what the site wants from you, isn't even a correct spelling, it is enough if it is comprehensible. Your question weren't. Btw, skilled programmers spell relative correctly even if they aren't native English speakers. It is not due to a direct correlation, simply because they are smart.

Comment: Aren't you from Turkey?

Comment: @peterh taking care of spelling instead of problem shows everything about you. First thing that normal programmers are interested in is  question that is problem. If you understand the question there is no big problem. Actually, fixing spelling is also important but it should not be the first priority for a real programmer. it is like your job. Meanwhile I am from Turkey. Why did you care about my country?

Comment: That is true, but spelling correctly is an automatic thing for any smart people. They don't require to prioritize between "writing good posts" and "spelling correctly", because the second is trivial for them. And highly skilled programmers are smart. This is why you can't find anybody here with a high reputation and without proper spelling. But, if you still won't, it is also not a problem, until your question is comprehensible. Your question weren't - until I fixed it.

Comment: Btw, editing questions doesn't get any "points" to me. More exactly: if I do this in the context of reviewing, I get a golden badge after 1000 reviews, but it doesn't make any privilege to me.

Comment: I am completely sure that u are a really stupid. There is not a direct relation between spelling and intelligence. If so, all exams would contain spelling questions. I do not want to waste my time with such a  foolish person. Go and correct another post dorky.

Comment: Up voted just to bring it back to 0 from whom ever down voted, assuming its this guy who's having an argument on spelling. I understand it was difficult to get what they wanted, but I still managed to work it out :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PrimeFaces uses jQuery UI so I've linked this : stackoverflow.com/questions/16924081/… - You could also disable all themeing and theme it yourself. This is a CSS/Layout issue not a direct primefaces requirement.

PrimeFaces guides on there website advises how to disable theming.